# Countable, self-similar total orders

Tags: logic, set-theory, order-theory, fractals

A total order $I$ is said to be weakly self-similar if there exists a proper subset $J \subsetneq I$ together with a bijective, order-preserving function $f:I \to J$ (that is, $J$ is isomorphic to $I$). Analogously, $I$ is said to be strongly self-similar if there exists an element $i \in I$ such that one of the total orders
$$I_{< i}, I_{\le i}, I_{> i}, I_{\ge i}$$
is isomorphic to $I$. Such sets are defined as you imagine, e.g. $I_{< i} = \{ x \in I: x < i \}$.

> Does there exist self-similar total orders on a countable set, whether in a weak or strong sense?

Comment: What obvious countable total orders are there that you could try out to get some intuition?

Comment: I have tried with ordinals and yes, I can get weakly self-similar countable total orders like $\omega^{\omega}$. I should have mentioned this in the question. However, it seems like all the orders I try to get strong self-similarity are uncountable (e.g. the Cantor set).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I meant countable set. I specified this because it seems that there is a subtle difference between "on a countable set $X$ " and the order being itself countable (I guess as a subset of $X \times X$).

Comment: No, there is no difference: a reflexive relation on an infinite set has the same size as the set.

Comment: The rational numbers are another famous countable total order, which should be one the the first examples you investigate to explore questions about countable orders.

Comment: As you defined it, every total order with a minimum or maximum is strongly self-similar (but not necessarily weakly self-similar). In particular, each total order on a finite, non-empty set is strongly self-similar.

Comment: Also, every infinite ordinal is weakly self-similar, because you can just remove the $0$ from the start and the order type remains the same, just like removing $0$ from $\mathbb{N}$. You just put $1$ where $0$ was, $2$ where $1$ was etc. for every finite number.

Comment: I get it, thanks. If I consider $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ this is isomorphic to $T^0\mathbb{Q} :=\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1/2]$ and $T^1 \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q} \cap [1/2,1]$ by rescaling. The weird thing that misled me is that many of the "intersection sets" $\cap_{ n=1}^{\infty} T^{c_1} \ldots T^{c_n}\mathbb{Q}$ are empty, with $\textbf{c} := (c_1, \ldots, c_n, \ldots )$ being zeros and ones. In the construction I was considering, this cannot happen. That's why I couldn't get countable stuff. I was asking the wrong question to myself.

Comment: The example $\omega^\omega$ you mention has a "very strong" self-similarity property - for *every* $i$, we have that $I_{>i}$ and $I_{\ge i}$ are both order-isomorphic to $I$. In fact there's a much simpler ordinal that also has this property...

Comment: Indeed, I should have said that strong similarity is that both of the ends are isomorphic, otherwise $\omega$ and $\omega^{op}$ provide examples for both the left and right cases.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, the question is quite trivial: $\omega$ provides an example for both questions. Regarding a more stringent definition, that is $I_{<i}$ and $I_{\ge i}$ being both isomorphic to $I$, one can consider $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1)$ and splitting at any value $q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$, e.g. $q = 1/2$.

As a side note, observe that such countable total orders cannot define a "fractal behavior": if we define $T^0 I := I_{< i}, T^1 I := I_{\ge i}$ as the two orders in which $I$ is split, 'most' of the sets
$$ T^{\textbf{c}} I := \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} T^{c_n} \ldots T^{c_1} I$$
for $\textbf{c} := (c_1, \ldots, c_n, \ldots ) \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ will be empty, since there are uncountably many such intersections. This is what misled me...